# Псевдослучайное число

Tags: случайные-числа, псевдокод

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы найти функцию **f(t)**, генерирующую псевдослучайные числа на промежутке **[0;1)** с равномерным распределением. Результат работы функции должен быть одинаковым для одинаковых **t**

Comment: Что такое `t`? Номер ПС числа в последовательности? Или некий абстрактный параметр, возможно плавающего типа?

Comment: Это любое число на свете

Answer (score 2):

Классическая реализация (*линейный конгруэнтный метод* thnx to *MBo*) использует пространство чисел `[0..X-1]`. Желательно чтобы **X** был простым числом. Обычно используют `X=(2^N)-1` или `X=(2^N)+1`. Далее выбирается множитель **M** и шаг `L ∊ [0..X-1]`.

```
x(0) := t , t ∊ [0..X-1] 
x(i+1) := (x(i)*M+L) % X
```

Выбирать множитель **M** и шаг **L** нужно аккуратно, чтобы период повтора цикла генерации был максимальным (**X** штук, т.е. все по одной). Результатом функции будет число `x(i+1)` делённое на **X**.

```
random() := x(i+1)/X
```

Comment: Ну так и добавьте имя этой классики - линейный конгруэнтный метод

Comment: Простите, но задача состоит в том, чтобы построить `f(t)`, т.е. фактически ГПСЧ *с произвольным доступом* (а не с последовательным доступом, как обычно делается у ГПСЧ-функций). В этом вся cуть задачи. То есть в любой момент у вас могут запросить `t`-тое случайное число в последовательности и вы должны его "вспомнить". Другими словами `f(0), f(1), f(2)...` - псевдослучайная последовательность и вы всегда должны давать один и тот же ответ на любое `f(i)`. Как вы это предлагаете сделать? Просто тупо запоминать все случайные числа в массиве? Для какого диапазона `t` вы сможете это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Если ваш параметр `t` - это именно индекс ПС числа в ПС последовательности, то [алгоритм Блюм-Блюма-Шуба](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BC_%E2%80%94_%D0%91%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%BC%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A8%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B0) генерирует ПС числа и при этом обладает тем свойством, что каждое число в ПС последовательности может быть вычислено напрямую, а не инкрементальным методом. Вам нужно лишь спроецировать диапазон на `[0, 1)`.

Другим вариантом решения задачи может быть применение алгоритма [блочного шифрования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80), который будет шифровать некую фиксированную последовательность данных (требуемой ширины), используя `t` в качестве ключа. (Или наоборот, шифровать `t` при помощи фиксированного ключа.)